# How to separate the performance of controls in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I would like to build a Manipulate object, for which some variables will be related to corresponding controls. For example, in this simple Manipulate object, if I change any slider control, both variables `mu1` and `mu2` are recalculated

```
Manipulate[
 S1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu1, 1], 10]; 
 S2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu2, 1], 10];
 TableForm[{S1, S2}],  {mu1, -1, 1}, {mu2, -1, 1}]
```

Is it possible to establish recalculation for each variable separately: when the 1st control is changed, only `mu1` is recalculated; when 2nd--- only `mu2`?

Answer (score 4):

Make `s1` and `s2` manipulate parameters with no controls and update them using `TrackingFunction` in controls `mu1` and `mu2`:

```
Manipulate[Style[#, 16] & @ TableForm[{s1, s2}],
 {mu1, -1, 1, TrackingFunction -> (mu1 = #; 
     s1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, 1], 5]; &)},
 {mu2, -1, 1, TrackingFunction -> (mu2 = #; 
     s2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, 1], 5]; &)},
 {{s1, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], 5]}, None},
 {{s2, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], 5] }, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yours works a lot better than mine does, this is definitely the correct solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

By using `Dynamic[]` we are able to localise variables, preventing the entire expression from updating.

```
Clear[S1];
Clear[S2];

S1[mu1_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu1, 1], 1][[1]];
S2[mu2_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu2, 1], 1][[1]];

Manipulate[
 {
   {{Table[Dynamic[S1[mu1]], 10]}},
   {{Table[Dynamic[S2[mu2]], 10]}}
 } // TableForm,
 {mu1, 0, 1},
 {mu2, 0, 1}
]
```

I see that you have been asking this question for over a year now on various forums, I hope that I helped you today.

Comment: In addition, it's also usually good practise to use the `TrackedSymbols` option of `Dynamic` to specify more precisely when each display element should update.

Comment: I hope you helped, but I don't remember about asking this question anywhere

Comment: @Konstantin you asked on Wolfram Community 1 year ago https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1809181

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot this question on Wolfram Community :((